# Is there a way to tell if its an Instagram creator or business account?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Recently Instagram introduced their new Creator profiles. Your Instagram account can now be one of the following: personal account, business account or creator account.

Not everything which is possible with a business account is also possible with a creator account. So I need a way in my application to determine if it's one or the other.

How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry for reopening this old topic, but I am in the same situation. Any luck finding this info via the Instagram Graph API and not the Instagram Basic API?

This is super relevant right now since some of the new implementations are only available for Business Accounts and not Creators, so differentiating between them is crucial to provide a good UX.

Comment: Currently, there is no way doing it with the Instagram Graph API. I ended up doing a request to https://www.instagram.com/${username}/?__a=1 and checking the attribute `is_business_account` which works fine for me but also has several potential pitfalls (e.g. Instagram blocking your IP if doing too many requests, etc.). @AndreaOlivato

Comment: Yeah exactly, you get blocked after a bit, especially if you do this for a lot of users. After a bit of testing, I've found a way by calling the endpoint for content creation and catching the exception, which throws a different code if the user is not business. I'll post more info in a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @RaideR for the question and the support in the comment.

Just to help everyone out there who doesn't want to scrape just to get such a basic info, it's actually possible to extract this by simulating an empty POST call to the /userid/media endpoint and catching the exception with code = 10, which indicates the account is a Creator. All other cases are Business Acccounts.

```
POST /userid/media 
CATCH FacebookResponseException
```

Below you can find my PHP code as reference, but you can apply the same logic in any language with any framework:

```
public function isBusiness() {
    try {
        $this->conn->post("/".$this->fb_id."/media", [], $this->getToken());
        return true;
    } catch (FacebookResponseException $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() == 10) {
        return false;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return true;
    }
 }
```

I wrote a [more extensive article here](https://andreaolivato.medium.com/distinguish-between-business-and-creators-with-the-instagram-graph-api-526c1465b8b0) if you want more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using Instagram Basic Display API. Example syntax is as follows:

```
GET https://graph.instagram.com/{user-id}
  ?fields=id,username,account_type
  &access_token={access-token}
```

A json will be returned. Returned account type will be one of the following:

```
BUSINESS, CONSUMER, CREATOR
```

For more information, refer to this link:
[Instagram Basic Display API/Reference/User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As far as I understand that correctly, I need to have an Instagram user access token for this. Unfortunately, I just have the Facebook user access token (Instagram Graph API).

Comment: Hi, I've took some research and this might be helpful. If you have username to check just make get request to `https://www.instagram.com/${username}/?__a=1` . For example if username is twicetagram, a get request to"https://www.instagram.com/twicetagram/?__a=1" will return json. `response.graphql.user.is_business_account` returns boolean that indicates whether twicetagram is a business account or not.

Comment: As of September 2023, you need to add the parameter `__d=dis` to the URL, so it's `https://www.instagram.com/${username}/?__a=1&__d=dis`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking rate limit usage

```
GET graph.facebook.com/{accountid}/content_publishing_limit&access_token={your_access_token}
```

If you are not a professional account, the error code {#10} will return.

```
error: {
   message: '(#10) The user is not an Instagram Business',
   type: 'OAuthException',
   code: 10,
}
```

otherwise response will be something like;

```
{ 
   "data": [{
    "quota_usage": 2
  }]
}
```

here is detailed info from developer's guide : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing#checking-rate-limit-usage